# iOS tableview with dynamic-height cells but all cells are displayed at once

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I would like to achieve the following:

- Table view with dynamic-height cells (this I could do, thanks to [this article](http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout).
- But the table view's height is set to all cell's dynamic height together, meaning that all cells are displayed in the table view at the same time

-> Basically a list of views which have dynamic height (using auto layout and wrapping labels), and I don't want to calculate heights-in-pixels if possible

[image]

Comment: to achieve dynamic height, you need to use UITableViewAutomaticRowDimension and set constraint properly within cell from top to bottom and left to right. and give estimated height using delegate method.

Comment: Did you read my whole post? I managed to do that, what I need additionally, that all cells are displayed at the same time (meaning, the tableview's height is set to the sum of all dynamic cells' height). Actually I want a stackview with dynamic-height items.

Comment: i read your post buddy. sorry i didn't understand. if you can share any image what you are saying then i can help you...as i am not able to get it your last line "stackview with dynamic-height item", you want to achieve this with tableview.?

Comment: have you added any bottom constraint to table, then you need to remove it. and add height constraint to table and it should be equal to self.table.contentSize.height. and then call layoutIfneeded. i am sure this will work. as i have done similar thing.

Comment: could you provide working code sample? bottom constraint is set for the 'marker' label, and there's a vertical constrainer between marker and the tableview. THe problem is that the tableview's height has to be dyamically set and I don't know when, how and to what value (I guess)

Comment: I set a height-constraint for the tableview with a fixed size in the IB. Then I access this constraint as an IBoutlet in the viewcontroller, after calling reloadData, I change the heightConstraint's constant to table.contentSize.height, then table.layoutIfNeeded, and still doesn't work (tableview remains fixed size, and only contains 1.5 cell not all of them).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80434/discussion-between-user3680929-and-csabi).

Answer (score 1):

From what you've said, it sounds like you want all cells to be visible at the same time so that the table doesn't scroll. If that's the case, do you really need to use `UITableView`?

It sounds like `UIStackView` is what you want, and it will do all the sizing automatically. This would effectively allow you to show a screen full of "cells", all sized correctly, without scrolling.

If you want to try the stack view approach, you can drag one in using Interface Builder. You can then add items to it directly in Interface Builder, or, if you are duplicating the same thing again and again and want to do it in code, then add them using `addArrangedSubview()` like this:

```
stackView.addArrangedSubview(yourView)
```

Comment: Plus, UIStackView is iOS 9 only.